# Which libraries do I need to connect a PostgreSql from a C program?

Tags: c, postgresql

I mean using just the old C, not C++ nor C#: Just C, because I need a little and fast executable with no screen output.

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/)?

Comment: Old C? The C11 standard is pretty modern by my book.

Comment: C++ can be faster than C in a lot of cases, especially if you're doing non-trivial code. If you're using a database the overhead of the interfacing language is usually minor anyway, Python or C# is probably fine.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-interfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`libpq`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq.html).

Instructions for building with `libpq` are [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-build.html).